# Do the DataFrames in Pandas panels have to have the same size?

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I want to make a panel that has multiple DataFrames, but each DataFrame has a different number of columns and rows.

For example:

`Name Value1 Value2 Value3
0  98p_1500kpa_R1      9      0      0
1  98p_1600kpa_R1     99      0      0
2               0    999      0      0
3               0   9999      0      0
             Name Column1 Column2 Column3
0  98p_1500kpa_R2    100    256    654
1  98p_1600kpa_R2    100    256    654`

I will be eventually be using matplotlib to plot various parameters within the panel.  From what it looks like, when I make the panel and display every item in it, it makes each DataFrame the same size by adding "NaN" to the rows and columns that don't exist.  Luckily I can still plotvalues in the DataFrame with the "NaN".  It also seems that it doesnt let me have different column names for each DataFrame, as shown below:

```
             Name Value1 Value2 Value3
0  98p_1500kpa_R1      9      0      0
1  98p_1600kpa_R1     99      0      0
2               0    999      0      0
3               0   9999      0      0
             Name Value1 Value2 Value3
0  98p_1500kpa_R2    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  98p_1600kpa_R2    NaN    NaN    NaN
2             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

My code:

```
R1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([4,4]), columns=['Name','Value1','Value2','Value3'])

R1.Name[0] = '98p_1500kpa_R1'
R1.Name[1] = '98p_1600kpa_R1'
R1.Value1[0] = 9
R1.Value1[1] = 99
R1.Value1[2] = 999
R1.Value1[3] = 9999

R2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([2,2]), columns=['Name','Column1'])
R2.Name[0] = '98p_1500kpa_R2'
R2.Name[1] = '98p_1600kpa_R2'
R2.Column1[0] = 10
R2.Column1[1] = 1000

speedline = pd.Panel({'R1': R1})
speedline['R2'] = R2

for key in speedline.items:
        print speedline[key]
```

Comment: Actually after looking at the underlying dfs this looks like it's a restriction that the axes shape must all be the same, though I can't find any docs to state this

Comment: That is what I was thinking unforunately.  Fortunately when I create the dfs I don't have to make those all the same size, the panel will just add the additional rows and columns.

Comment: It must be some kind of optimisation so it doesn't have to check the dimensions for each df when you perform some func on the panel

Comment: You probably want to instead use a list or dictionary of dataframes.  The fact that the dataframes in a panel have the same rows and columns is basically the whole point of the panel structure.

Comment: @JohnE When is that needed?

Comment: @wolfdawn  Well, this is an old question and panels are now deprecated in pandas.  But to answer the question, it would just depend on the use case and what is convenient for that use case.  I'm just saying that if you have 2 dataframes with different columns, it doesn't make sense to store them in the same dataframe but rather in different dataframes (potentially but not necessarily grouped in a list or dict)